# Average a range of values if the date associated with it falls within a date range

Tags: excel-formula, sumifs

I'm trying to average a range of values if its associated date falls between two specified dates.  The following function works:

`AVERAGEIFS($1:$1,$2:$2,">=1/1/2014",$2:$2,"<=1/2/2014")`

...in this case the values that you want to average are in row 1 and the dates that are associated with it are in row 2.

However, in this case I'm explicitly stating the date range in my formula (">=1/1/2014" and "<=1/2/2014").  Is there any way to create a similar formula that allows me to reference date cells to determine my date range instead of having to explicitly state the dates in the formula itself???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use the following, by putting the **start date** and the **end date** in another cell and refer to them in your formula:

```
=AVERAGEIFS($1:$1,$2:$2,">="&$B$4,$2:$2,"<="&$B$5)
```

with the following example:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your two dates are in E5 and F5 you could do it like this:

```
=AVERAGEIFS($1:$1,$2:$2,">="&E5,$2:$2,"<="&F5)
```